# Performance improvement over numpy.linalg.solve for systems of 50k x 50k

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

Currently I am using (I think serially unless the code is parallelized/optimized for shared memory) on multi-core AMD processor machines:

```
try:
    B = np.linalg.solve(F1, b)
except np.linalg.LinAlgError as e:
    print(str(e))
    raise
```

Where F1 is a full matrix with zeroes, that can be made sparse, 50kx50k square matrix of numpy float64's. I would greatly appreciate if I can improve memory as well as CPU performance  with another solver possibly using MPI. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/solving-very-large-matrices-in-pieces.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I am engineer, not a mathematician, I am not very familiar with Python either... I confess I would much prefer a recipe... I must be very pragmatic...